# How to take an 2D slice with Lens

Tags: haskell, slice, haskell-lens

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Lens
import Data.Vector.Lens

v = V.fromList [V.fromList [1..3], V.fromList [4..6], V.fromList [7..9]]
```

1D slice (for example) :

```
*Main> v ^. sliced 1 2
fromList [fromList [4,5,6],fromList [7,8,9]]
```

2D sclice:  What should I write to get this result?

```
*Main> v ^. sliced 1 2 {- ??????? -}  sliced 0 2   --  Or not so?
V.fromList [V.fromList [4,5], V.fromList [7,8]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
insliced :: Int -> Int -> Lens' (V.Vector (V.Vector a)) (V.Vector (V.Vector a))
insliced i n f m = f (V.map (V.slice i n) m)
    <&> V.zipWith (\a b -> a V.// zip [i..i+n-1] (V.toList b)) m
```

then

```
λ v ^. sliced 1 2 . insliced 0 2
fromList [fromList [4,5],fromList [7,8]]
```

This has similar requirements to `sliced` to be valid.

It's worth mentioning there's a general version of this called `column` from `linear`. It can't be used with `Vector` because `Vector`s aren't `Representable` (because because it's size isn't statically known). But with something like `V3`:

```
λ V3 (V3 1 2 3) (V3 4 5 6) (V3 7 8 9) ^. _yz . column _xy
V2 (V2 4 5) (V2 7 8)
```

You could write your own (less safe) version for vectors:

```
vcolumn :: ALens' a b -> Lens' (V.Vector a) (V.Vector b)
vcolumn l f m = f (V.map (^# l) m) <&> V.zipWith (\a b -> a & l #~ b) m
```